# List<String> empty, but values return after reload

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to load different values from a .txt file line by line.

I'm loading an file from assets, which is already registered in pubspec.yaml.

```
Future<String> getFileData() async {
  return await rootBundle.loadString('assets/files/text.txt');
}
```

As this returns one long String I split it into a list:

```
void doStuff() async {
  await getFileData().then((value) => value.split('\n').forEach((element) {
        exampleQuestions.add(element);
      }));
}
```

This method is called in my class - constructor which is called from my Main by a named route:

```
  GameOver.routeName: (context) => GameOver(),
    '/game': (context) => Game(

        ),
  },
```

exampleQuestion get's filled in the doStuff() - method (already checked that), but looses it's values in the _GameState class where the widget, that want's to access the list returns an out of index exception.

However if i quick reload my application the values are set correctly. If I then click the button to continue again nothing changes until I quick reload.

Any hints are very appreciated ..

Comment: try to use `setState` method when you add elements to the list

Answer (score 1):

You should not call asynchronous methods like this in widget constructors, because they'll be called on every build.

You should use a `StatefulWidget` with a `FutureBuilder` instead.

On another note, `LineSplitter` should be used for splitting lines.

```
class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  late final Future<List<String>> _exampleQuestionsFuture;

  static Future<String> _getFileData() => rootBundle.loadString('assets/files/text.txt');

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _exampleQuestionsFuture = _getFileData().then(const LineSplitter().convert);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<String>>(
      future: _exampleQuestionsFuture,
      builder: (snapshot, data) {
        /* ... */
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
How can I read from the Future<List<String>> now ? 
I tried something like: 

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
     _getFileData().then(const LineSplitter().convert).then((value) {
       setState(() {
         question = value.elementAt(currentRound);
       });
    });

but from my understainding this makes no sense, because the value is only updated once.

Comment: question: _exampleQuestionsFuture.then((value) => value.elementAt(currentRound)) ,

returns with cannot applie Future<String> to String

Comment: Use the `snapshot` in `FutureBuilder`. `FutureBuilder` is made for single-use `Future`s.

Comment: Great! Be sure to mark this answer as accepted if it worked for you.

Comment: How can i get the length of the _exampleQuestionsFuture now? I tried different approches, but always run into the problem , that at some point i cannot convert Future<int> to int